# Ajax not working on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, web-sockets

Sometimes I see the "new question with activity message", my score increments automatically without refreshing, "an edit was made, click to refresh" and all other [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) responses. 90% of the time this doesn't work, and I have to refresh manually to get all the updates. Why?

I am running Windows XP SP3, Firefox 24.0 with a handful of add-ons *(I tried running with add-ons disabled, and the problem remains)*.

I noticed by looking at the [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29) console that I get the following error whenever I navigate to Stack Overflow:

```
NetworkError: 502 Bad Gateway - http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/"
```

I don't know if it relates to the problem.

(I send the administrators this question and they told me to ask here, so here we are.)

Comment: Are you behind a proxy of some sort?

Comment: What does http://websocketstest.com/ say? All green?

Comment: @perhapsPekka No, but you gave me something to try. I will try to use a proxy and see what happens.

Comment: @Oded Not all green, both port 80 and port 8080 are failing the tests.

Comment: @Oded here is the [**test**](http://websocketstest.com/result/260881).

Comment: @perhapsPekka After testing with a proxy server the problem remains, now I get 403 forbidden response for the `http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/`.

Comment: You need to look into the causes for port 80 being blocked. Firewall? ISP?

Comment: @Oded I tried a proxy server but it didn't work. There is no firewall installed except for windows firewall.

Comment: @Sniffer - I wouldn't expect web sockets to work until you manage to get port 80 green on the test site.

Comment: @Oded OK Thank you for help. I will look into why those two aren't working.

Comment: @probablyPekka I have edited my answer to his question, please check edit.

Comment: @Oded I have edited my answer to his question, please check edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to helpful comments from both @perhaps Pekka and @Oded, I was able to narrow down the cause of the problem to WebSockets not working on port 80, thus not getting real time feedback from the server.

The actual reason for WebSockets not working on Port seems to be caused by the ISP, because when I tried to connect through the Tor network I started to get feedback immediately.

## Edit:

This is Day: 27, Month: 10, Year: 2013. I noticed that websockets are working correctly today even though when I run the tests against [websocketstest.com](http://www.websocketstest.com) I still get the same results, I am not using any proxy servers as well. Things just started to work on their own.

One thing I have noticed that changed is that now by looking at Firebug I can see that my browser tries to connect to `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` instead of `http://sockets.ny.stackexchange.com/` which might be the reason. until I make sure I will ask the admins.

## Answer to edit:

As @Marc Gravell has explained in his comment, `qa.sockets.stackexchange.com` uses `wss://` protocol and thus SSL which is better and obviously works in my case. @Oded has told me before that Stackoverflow is switching to secure websockets and they have delivered as promised.

**Thanks to all Stackoverflow team for their amazing job !**

Comment: Some ISPs use caching proxies to save bandwidth, and they far too often just kill websocket traffic (mostly, unknowingly). That's why we're going to SSL for websockets, since it should bypass proxies automatically.

Comment: @TimPost I hope you get that done ASAP, I am looking forward to it. Great job guys and Thank You.

Comment: What you might also notice is that "qa.sockets..." is actually "wss://", where-as "sockets.ny..." is "ws://" - basically, "qa" is our web-socket provider over SSL, which works much better with meddling intermediaries like proxies and ISPs, because they can't see that the data isn't actually http.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you very much. Oded told me that you were switching to `wss` but I didn't notice that when I looked at Firebug. This must have fixed the problem because when I visit [websocketstest](websocketstest.com) I can see that websockets work without any problems over SSL connections. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sniffer sorry if it has taken a while - unfortunately, at stackoverflow scale it isn't quite as simple as "add this library" or "enable this switch" - iirc in this case we were working iteratively with the author of haproxy to work through issues

Comment: @MarcGravell I think you did a great job, thank you again.

Comment: Hello @MarcGravell, What happened ? It looks like we are back to square one, after Stackoverflow went down for maintenance and came back I found that websockets aren't working again and it seems because you went back to use non SSL solution ? Why so ? Thank you.

Comment: @Sniffer so had a network outage earlier due to some network device issues. While we investigate and repair we've defaulted to minimum impact, meaning: WS rather than WSS for now. Will be back real soon.

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the up to date information, hope you get this fixed soon.

Comment: @Sniffer to be clear: AFAIK the wss  was not part of the problem - simply part of our "strip down the system to get back online asap"